# jQuery Validation is placing span element for the error even when there is no error to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a project that is written with `c#` on the top of ASP.NET MVC5. I am using [css-bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) top design my site. I am also using [jQuery-Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) along with [jquery-validation-unobtrusive](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) to handle client-side validation.

For some reason the `jQuery-Validation` insert a `span` element under the input even with there is no error. This causes extra space to appear under the input which is not desired.

How can I prevent `jQuery-Validation` package from inserting the error container if there is no error?

Here is the order in which I include these packages into my html-layout

1. `jquery.validate.min.js` this is the jquery-validation package
2. `jquery.validate.setup.js` this is my own config for the jquery-validation package
3. `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` this is the jquery.validate.unobtrusive package
4. `query.validate.unobtrusive.setup.js` this is my own config for the jquery.validate.unobtrusive package

Here is the content of my `jquery.validate.setup.js` file

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden:not('.force-validaion'), .ignore",
    highlight: function (element, _errorClass, _validClass) {

        $(element).closest('.form-group,.form-group-custom.input-group,.input-group-custom').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, _errorClass, _validClass) {

        $(element).closest('.help-block-error-placeholder').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Here is the content of my `query.validate.unobtrusive.setup.js` file

```
var settings = {
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block help-block-error-placeholder",
    debug: true,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var elm = $(element);
        var parent = elm.closest('.input-group,.input-group-custom');

        if (parent.length) {
            error.insertAfter(parent);
        }
        else if (elm.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || elm.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(elm.closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)').first());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(elm);
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        showLoading();
        form.submit();
    }
};

$.validator.unobtrusive.options = settings;
```

For some reason after the input loses focus, the following span is added even when there is no error

```
<span id="INPUT_NAME-error" class="help-block help-block-error-placeholder"></span>
```

How can I prevent this `span` element from being inserted unless there is an error?

Comment: Is this only happening after the input field loses focus? Is this happening to all the input fields or just one? What error is it showing you? Do you have any errors showing up in your console?

Comment: @crazymatt it is added on all inputs. once you click on input then click away from it the span is inserted with empty value as the text value for the span. I do not get any JS errors in the console

Comment: The `@Html.ValidationMesssageFor()` generates a `<span>` element as the placeholder. When there is a client side validation error, another `<span>` element containing the error text is inserted into the containing `<span>` (and the inner `<span>` is removed if the value is valid. Its not clear what you are wanting to achieve with your custom js functions

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Validate plugin is going to add this `span` to contain any validation error messages.  Then it's going to toggle these elements when the error messages are toggled.

You're setting it to `span` here...

```
var settings = {
    errorElement: "span" 
    ....
```

By default (if you leave out the `errorElement` option), the plugin is going to create `label` elements.

I'm not sure how an invisible `span` is able to take up space in your layout, but it surely has something to do with your CSS, which we cannot see.

My suggestion is to try removing `errorElement` to revert to the default `label` element.  When there is no error message, this hidden element should take up zero space in your layout.  Otherwise, if you must use a `span` for some reason, then you're going to have to inspect your live DOM to troubleshoot your CSS.